# Iter over dict and display object.item django template

Tags: python, django, jinja2

I have three contacts to display on my page, and instead of writing three times the contact

```
div div div object.first /div /div /div
div div div object.second /div /div /div
div div div object.last /div /div /div
```

I would prefer to do something like

```
contacts = ['first', 'second', 'third']
```

In python view

```
{% for field in contacts_fiels %}
    div div div {{ object.field }} /div /div /div
{% endfor %}
```

Any idea ?

Edit :

I have something like :

(view.py)

```
object.first = 'user1'
object.second = 'user2'
object.third = 'user3'
contacts_fields = ['first', 'second', 'third']
```

And then the jinja loop to iter on objects with fields registered in contacts_fields, to have

```
div div div user1 /div /div /div
div div div user2 /div /div /div
div div div user3 /div /div /div
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass the list named contacts as an **context object** from your view. This is accomplished as follows.

views.py

```
return render(request, 'views/index.html', context={"values":[1,2,3,4]})
```

index.html

```
{% for val in values %}
<div>
    <div>
        <div>Val is {{ val }}</div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

For further reading, you can refer to the [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/shortcuts/#optional-arguments).

Comment: I'm not sure that my intention was clear.

I have object.first = 'user1'
object.second = 'user2'
object.third = 'user3'

And would like to make an array
array = ['first', 'second', 'third']

Anyway your solution works, I'm just not sure that you understood what I intended to do. More than "I need a solution for do something that will work", I ask for know if this could be something possible.

Thanks anyway

Comment: @InMax83 No worries.

I think what you want is `contacts = object.__dict__.values()`.

Alternatively, if you want support for objects which don't have a `__dict__` you could use `dir(object)` and perform custom filtering thereon.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very simple example view which sends the contacts list to the template using the context dictionary argument in the returned render

```
def myView(request):

    contacts = ["A", "B", "C"]

    return render(request, "myTemplate.html", {"contacts": contacts}
```

Now in the template, you can add something like this to display the strings in the `contacts` list:

```
{% for c in contacts %}
    <div>c</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Now if your `contacts` is based on a django object, you can replace your list with `Contact.objects.all()` (or however you are filtering it). So you would end up with something like:

```
def myView(request):

    contacts = Contact.objects.all()

    return render(request, "myTemplate.html", {"contacts": contacts}
```

Doing this you could then display the different field values of the Contact object in your template as a table simply as so:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Field Name A</th>
            <th>Field Name B</th>
            <th>Field Name C</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for c in contacts %}
            <tr>
                <td>c.fieldA</td>
                <td>c.fieldB</td>
                <td>c.fieldD</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```